# Dispatching an event for a closed socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm doing event for disconnect client.
Here is my code:

```
public void run(){
    while(isConnected()){
        System.out.println("asd");          
    }
    serverListener.clientDisconnect(clientID);
}

public boolean isConnected(){
    if(socket.isClosed() || !socket.isConnected() || socket.isInputShutdown() || socket.isOutputShutdown()){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is I have this results:
isClosed = false
isConnected = true
IsInputShutdown = false
IsOutputShutdown = false

And when a client disconnects, I have the same result: nothing happens.

Comment: You have no way to know that the socket is closed on the other end. You should use socket timeout on each side. Normally I use socket timeout and send a keep-alive every X seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.  Those flags tell you about what you did.

You haven't closed the connection, it was connected once, you haven't shutdown the input or the output.

The only way to know if the connection is closed is when you fail to read from the socket. (Or your Selector notifies you)

Note: just because the other end has closed the connection, doesn't mean you want to close.  Imagine you have a HTTP request and your server sends you the response and closes the connection. Do you want the connection to close even if you haven't read all the data, at some random point, possibly before you have finish or even started?  You don't, you want to know it was closed once you have read all the data.

Comment: I fix now! I fix now:

public void run(){
while(true){
if(packetType == 1) {
try {
String string = getString();
serverListener.readString(string);
} catch (IOException e) {
break;
}
} else if(packetType == 2){
try {
byte[] bytes = getByteArray();
serverListener.readByteArray(bytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
break;
}
}
}
serverListener.clientDisconnect(clientID);
}

Answer (score 0):

Check what happens with this code:

```
public void run(){
    while(true){ 
        if(packetType == 1) {
            try { 
                String string = getString(); 
                serverListener.readString(string);
            } catch (IOException e) { break; }
        } else if(packetType == 2){
            try { 
                byte[] bytes = getByteArray();
                serverListener.readByteArray(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { break; }
        } 
    } 
    serverListener.clientDisconnect(clientID);
}
```